# parsing csv via C++

Tags: c++, parsing, csv

Good evening, I've got the following problem. I am parsing csv file like this:

```
entry1;entry2;entry3
entry4;entry5;entry6
;;
```

I'm getting entries this way:

```
stringstream iss;
while(getline(file, string) {
iss << line;
     while(getline(iss, entry, ';') {
     /do something
     }
}
```

But I've got a problem with last row (;;) where I did read only 2 entries, I **need to read the third blank entry**. How can I do it?

Comment: I wouldn't use `stringstream` for this, just split each line at the semicolons.

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120140/csv-parser-in-c?rq=1)

Comment: I can't use <vector>, it's forbidden by evaluation computer.

Comment: Then what may you use? You can just replace the `vector.push_back(...) `with your `do something`

Comment: I can use only these: #include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <cctype>
#include <stdint.h>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I should point out a problem in the code, your `iss` is in the fail state after reading the first line and then calling `while(getline(iss, entry, ';'))`, so after reading every line you need to reset the `stringstream`. The reason it is in the fail state is that the end of file is reached on the stream after calling `std:getline(iss, entry, ';'))`.

For your question, one simple option is to simply check whether anything was read into `entry`, for example:

```
stringstream iss;
while(getline(file, line)) {
iss << line; // This line will fail if iss is in fail state
entry = ""; // Clear contents of entry
     while(getline(iss, entry, ';')) {
         // Do something
     }
     if(entry == "") // If this is true, nothing was read into entry
     { 
         // Nothing was read into entry so do something
         // This doesn't handle other cases though, so you need to think
         // about the logic for that
     }
     iss.clear(); // <-- Need to reset stream after each line
}
```

Comment: I've got iss.clear(); in my code byt I didn't paste it here. I've solved my problem this way: if ';' is on the end of the line, do something ;) SO thanks, my problem is solved.

Comment: @user2129659: Okay, make sure you don't leave out any important code when posting a question though.